# what happens if empty object is passed to where in sequelizejs query?

Tags: sequelize.js

My app needs to query a table with conditions being passed in `sqlobj`. Here is the sequelizejs code:

```
let _item = await ModelA.findAll({where:sqlobj});  //what happens if sqlobj is {}?
```

If `sqlobj` passed in is an empty object {}, it means that all records in `ModelA` shall be selected. Is the understanding above correct in sequelizejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `logging: console.log` or any logging function of yours as a parameter to `findAll`

`let _item = await ModelA.findAll({where:{}, logging: console.log});`

This will print the corresponding query executed on the RDBMS. To answer your question yes it does fetch all records.

Comment: besides to empty {}, undefined passed to `where` selects all records in the table as well.